MT5Manager in Python
I need to connect to an MetaQuotes server via the MT5Manager API (not the regular consumer version). I double checked the credentials, but it is failing to connect without any helpful message.
`from MT5Manager import ManagerAPI

def main():
    # Initialize ManagerAPI object

    # Specify server, login, and password
    server = "MT5SERVER:443"
    login = 1234  # Your MT5 account login
    password = "*******************"

    # Initialize ManagerAPI object with server, login, and password
    manager = ManagerAPI(server=server, login=login, password=password)

    # Connect to MetaTrader 5 Manager
    res = manager.Connect()
    if not res:
        print("Failed to connect to MetaTrader 5 Manager")
        return


    # Subscribe to EURUSD ticks
    if not manager.symbol_subscribe("EURUSD"):
        print("Failed to subscribe to EURUSD ticks")
        manager.disconnect()
        return

    # Retrieve ticks for EURUSD
    ticks = manager.get_ticks("EURUSD")

    if ticks is not None:
        print("Ticks for EURUSD:")
        for tick in ticks:
            print(tick)

    # Disconnect from MetaTrader 5 Manager
    manager.disconnect()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
`

Any suggestions?
Connect() returns False.

# include the library
import MT5Manager

# create the graphical interface
manager = MT5Manager.ManagerAPI()
# connect the server
if manager.Connect("192.168.1.100:443", 1001, "1234Qwe!", 
                    MT5Manager.ManagerAPI.EnPumpModes.PUMP_MODE_USERS, 120000):
    # get the list of managers on the server
    managers = manager.UserGetByGroup("managers\\*")
    # check the obtained list
    if managers is not False:
        print(f"There are {len(managers)} managers on server")
    else:
        # failed to get the list
        print(f"Failed to get manager list: {MT5Manager.LastError()}")
    # disconnect from the server
    manager.Disconnect()
else:
    # failed to connect to the server
    print(f"Failed to connect to server: {MT5Manager.LastError()}")


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
